# Querying Parse for ObjectId

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, xcode7

I would like to query Parse to obtain the object ids of a table and place it into an array. I have attempted to do this but for some reason the array ends up empty or I can not utilize it in another function. Currently I have hard coded the ids but would like some help query and placing them into an array. Currently my code is :

```
func GetRandomObjectID(){
    ObjectIDs = ["objectid1","objectid2","objectid3","objectid4","objectid5","objectid6","objectid7"]
    RandomID = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(ObjectIDs.count)))
}

func CallData(){
    GetRandomObjectID()
    var query : PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "QuestionsandAnswers")
    query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(ObjectIDs[RandomID]){
        (ObjectHolder : PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if (error == nil) {
            self.Question = ObjectHolder!.valueForKey("Question") as? String
            self.Answers = ObjectHolder!.valueForKey("Answers") as? Array
            self.Answer = ObjectHolder!.valueForKey("Answer") as? String
            if(self.Answers.count > 0){
                self.questionLabel.text = self.Question
                self.Button1.setTitle(self.Answers[0], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
                self.Button2.setTitle(self.Answers[1], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
                self.Button3.setTitle(self.Answers[2], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
                self.Button4.setTitle(self.Answers[3], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            }
        } else {
            NSLog("There is something wrong!")
        }
    }
}
```

Any advice? I am using swift, xcode7, and parse as my backend.

Comment: You mention putting them into an array or table, and you have included the code for downloading the data, but not the code for putting it into the array. It is hard to see what is wrong without the whole picture. In addition, what do you mean by `hard coded the array`?

Comment: ObjectIDs = ["objectid1","objectid2","objectid3","objectid4","objectid5","objectid6","objectid7"] -> this is the hard coding the array

Comment: the last code I used to try and retrieve the ids was `   var query = PFQuery(className: "myClassName")
        
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (ids, error:NSError?) -> Void in
            if(error == nil ){
                //success
                
                for id in ids! {
                    self.ObjectIDs.append(id["objectId"] as! String)
                   
                }
               
            }else {
                print(error)
                
            }
        }
       
    }  `

Comment: But the array returns empty when I attempt to use it in the CallData()

Comment: I do not understand why you would think that this line works: `query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(ObjectIDs[RandomID])` You get a random `objectId` from your array of `objectIds`, but none of the `objectIds` in the array are valid. You cannot make up your own. They have to be randomly generated by Parse, like so: `ebHcZOXTQk`

Comment: its ok I got it worked out and that line does work